# Oracle driver template is not showing in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ojdbc

so i'm working on a dynamic web project and i'm trying setting up a new a connection profile -> new driver definition, there is no other driver besides generic JDBC Driver, i don't know if i missed something. so yes please help(btw i already have installed JBoss tools)

I did these steps ,but no use plz help me with this

1. Select Window > Preferences from the main menu bar.

   Expand Data Management > Connectivity and select Driver Definitions.

   Click Add.

   In the Name/Type tab, select a driver template.**(**here the driver template is not showing beside of generic jdbc ,I wnat oracle template)****

   (Optional) Select a Vendor Filter to display only those databases
   for a specific vendor.

   Select a driver template.

   (Optional) Modify the Driver Name if a driver definition with this
   name already exists.

   In the JAR List tab, indicate the path to the JAR or ZIP file
   associated with the driver.

   Click Add JAR/Zip.

   Browse to the location of the JAR or ZIP file.

   Click Open.

   (Optional) In the Properties tab, modify the default properties for
   the driver definition template.

Comment: Are the drivers something you need to install, as part of Eclipse?

Comment: yes i wanted to work with oracle thin driver but the template is not there of oracle type just only generic jdbc is present

Comment: I got the solution..Go to Help-->install new software -->from drop down list select 2022-03 - https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03/---->Database Development--->select required files---->install it... Problem solved